# Regular Expression of Bash and TCL

Tags: tcl

Are Regular Expressions(REs) of BASH and TCL same?

Can i put same BASH REs in `regexp` function of TCL and will it give me same result?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tcl.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash regular expressions are [documented](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-_005b_005b) as:

> When [the ‘=~’ operator] is used, the string to the right of the operator is considered an extended regular expression and matched accordingly (as in regex3)).

Tcl
regular expressions are [documented](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm#M4) as:

> DIFFERENT FLAVORS OF REs
>
> Regular expressions (“RE”s), as defined by POSIX, come in two flavors: extended REs (“ERE”s) and basic REs (“BRE”s). EREs are roughly those of the traditional egrep, while BREs are roughly those of the traditional ed. This implementation adds a third flavor, advanced REs (“ARE”s), basically EREs with some significant extensions.
>
> This manual page primarily describes AREs. BREs mostly exist for backward compatibility in some old programs; they will be discussed at the end. POSIX EREs are almost an exact subset of AREs. Features of AREs that are not present in EREs will be indicated.

So, you can use a bash regular expression with the Tcl regex engine, but not necessarily the other way around.

Note that bash regular expressions may have extra quoting that would need to be altered for Tcl.